# Dell Server Power On after power outage

Tags: power-supply, power, rack

I have a Dell PowerEdge R900, No UPS direct power connected, I do have it connected via a power strip(Surge Protector). but issue happens either ways

***Issue***

1. Server was powered off
2. I had a one second power outage
3. Server Powered on

How to avoid server from just powering on just because of power outage?

Comment: Have you tried to search for an answer? I just tried Google and DuckDuckGo with the phrase "computer powering on after power outage", both gave me articles explaining how to enable this feature. You could try to read them and figure out how to reverse it.

Comment: "I would refer to that as "resuming previous state" after an outage.  I have often seen BIOS options in desktop machines that allow you to specify what action you want taken after an outage.  The three typical options are: 1) stay off, 2) turn on, and 3) resume previous state." https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-Hardware-General/disabling-auto-power-on-after-power-outage/td-p/815354

Comment: @primohacker that's an answer